# Run Javascript on button click and execution of controller path

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, action

I have the following code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ConfirmBid", "Lot"))
{
    ...
    <input name="button" value="Place bid" type="submit" class="btn btn-size2" />
    ...
}
```

I want to run some JavaScript code when the button is pressed but only if the controller method ConfirmBid goes to a specific line of code (a success path).  How might this be achieved?

Comment: your question is very unclear.can you make it some clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return JavaScriptResult from your action, that will execute js written in return value. See: http://mazharkaunain.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-use-aspnet-mvc-javascriptresult.html

Answer (score 1):

Just output that javascript code you want to run conditionally.  Perhaps something like this:

Output this for "failure" branch:

```
<input name="button" value="Place bid" type="submit" class="btn btn-size2" />
```

Output this for "success" branch":

```
<input name="button" value="Place bid" type="submit" class="btn btn-size2" onclick="return some_js_function()" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function some_js_function() {
    // your logic here
}
```

Comment: Problem is I want the button click to run some code as long as the action method takes a particular path - I don't see how this will help.